# How to find "To scene range" in Blender 3.6.2 LTS Version?

Tags: animation, keyframes, dopesheet

[image]

How to find "To scene range" in Blender 3.6.2 LTS Version?
I am using blender 3.3.10 LTS then updated to 3.6 and i cant find this button.

Comment: Can't find it on an older version either and I actually have never seen it before in any of my Blender versions. Is it perhaps from an add-on which you have not installed/enabled in the new version?

Comment: There's no mention of it in any of the Blender manuals either.

Comment: You can find this button in Blender 3.3 in Animation tab,but when you use Version 3.5 or above the button is disappear. maybe they remove it? 
I dont use any add-ons for this button/feature. this feature help me so much .
I also read the manual and there's nothing about it, I found this button from tutorial but i forget which tutorial i watch